# Units of SASA generated from GROMACS gmx_sasa?

Tags: gromacs, surfaces

I'm wanting to use [gmx sasa](https://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/5.1/onlinehelp/gmx-sasa.html). I've done this on some residues I'm interested in analyzing. When I look at the output, I expect some value of $\pu{nm^2}$ or maybe $\pu{\unicode[.8,0]{x212B}^2}$. Instead, the `.xvg` file that is output has the following:

```
#   gmx_mpi sasa -f md_nojump.xtc -s md.tpr -n dyes.ndx -o gromacsSASA.xvg -odg gromacsSASADeltaG.xvg -or gromacsSASAAverage.xvg -tv gromacsSASAVolume.xvg -e 2010000 -pbc -rmpbc -probe 0.14 -ndots 24
# gmx sasa is part of G R O M A C S:
#
# Glycine aRginine prOline Methionine Alanine Cystine Serine
#
@    title "Solvent Accessible Surface"
@    xaxis  label "Time (ps)"
@    yaxis  label "Area (nm\S2\N)"
@TYPE xy
@ view 0.15, 0.15, 0.75, 0.85
@ legend on
@ legend box on
@ legend loctype view
@ legend 0.78, 0.8
@ legend length 2
@ s0 legend "Total"
      0.000   11.749
     10.000   11.430
     20.000   11.209
     30.000   11.114
     40.000   11.620
     50.000   11.810
     60.000   10.976
     70.000   11.592
     80.000   10.932
...
```

Here is a sample of what the atoms I'm interested. They are a part of a DNA-ligand type system. They are about 120 atoms total I'm looking at.

[image: Molecules analyzed by gmx SASA]
Does anyone know what that area unit is? It looks something like (nm)(seconds^-2)(Newton^-1). This would not be an area unit if that's the case, so this doesn't make sense to me.

Or maybe it is nm^2/(number of dots)?. I think that might make sense, but the GROMACS documentation doesn't say. The paper they reference that talks about the algorithm doesn't give any kind of hints for units either.

Comment: +1. Can you show the whole output file? If it were to be nm/s^2/N, wouldn't we have `/` instead of \? Also the characters used for picoseconds are `ps` not `pS` so I would be surprised if seconds^2 were to use a capital `s`. Perhaps the `S2` stands for "superscript 2". I think we need more information, such as your exact input and full output. Can you try this on a system where you know the area will be exactly 1 nm^2, and then see if that's what you get?

Comment: Exact Input is tricky since those files are big, but I'll edit to include a picture of the molecules I'm interested in, and some of the number outputs

Comment: Please include the input even if it's a few thousand characters. If it's beyond the site's limits, then please upload it to the "Modeling Matters" github repository in a folder named according to this question number (see the URL of your question).

Comment: The .xtc file is over 100MB so GitHub gave me some warning it won't be accepted. I don't think I can share that easily.

Comment: Can you compress it using `xz -k -8 file.xtc` in Linux? That's a beautiful picture by the way! I'm glad you added that!!

Comment: I would also be suspicious of the `S2` and assume it probably means something different than seconds squared. I have tried to Google around if this has been discussed anywhere, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: You all bring up good points about `s2` vs `S2`. Right now I think it is safe to assume that unit is already something like `area^2`, but one can never be so sure. I'll look at compress the `.xtc` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unit is actually $\pu{nm^2}$. What is written there is not is not specific to GROMACS, but to the plotting program it is using [Xmgrace](https://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/fonts.html). `\S` denotes the start of superscript font, which ends when it encounters a `\N`.

If you pass this file as an input to Xmgrace, it should produce a plot of surface area ($\pu{nm^2}$) vs time ($\pu{ps}$).

Comment: +1. What a bizarre markup language. Matlab and matplotplib use TeX: `^2` and I think Techplot used HTML: `<sup>2</sup>`. Xmgrace just had to go ahead and make their own thing.

Comment: Very weird. Glad you could provide an answer!